# After login using Ctrl+Alt+F1 getting only wallpaper

Tags: unity, system-installation, virtual-console

I am trying to install Ubuntu 15.04 on an ASUS computer. Everything looks OK during the installation and I pick a password. Then I try to login the screen goes black and then I am back at the login prompt. On this forum I have been told to press Ctrl+Alt+F1 and login and then put some code in to make it all work, but I can't log in. Then I press Ctrl+Alt+F1, it reads my computer name and login: I type my password and I can see it as I type. I am then told to type my password. Then I do that the cursor doesn't move and then I press Enter and I am told that the login is incorrect.

I got it to work and put the code in to update and then reboot, but then I try to login I type the password and hit Enter, and I end up with a blank brown/purple Ubuntu wallpaper, no icons, no toolbars, nothing.

What is wrong?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

Answer (score 1):

First it asks for your **username**, not your password. If you type your username, **then it will ask for password**. Type your password there. Also you can type `Alt+F7` to get a graphical interface.

Comment: If this post helped you, please mark this as answer.

Comment: I did it and i got it to work and put the code in to update and then reboot but then i try to login i type the password and hit enter i end up with a blank brown/purple Ubuntu wallpapper, no ikons no bars, nothing. What is wrong?

Comment: Would you be able to share a screenshot? You can use [this](http://imgur.com/) site to upload and share the url

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/CWwxShZ.jpg this is the best I can do.

Comment: are you using logging in using systemd? if yes, select the upstart version from the grub menu.

Comment: what is grub menu?

Comment: At the time of booting, the screen with a purple-color background showing list of installed operating systems, from where you click Ubuntu to start Ubuntu.